# Add element to array

Tags: java, android, arrays

I got this first class

```
 public class Etaj   {

 int [][] etaj1,etaj2,etaj3,etaj4;

    public void creazaEtaje()
    {
        etaj1 = new int[1][9];


    }
 }
```

and the second class its here

```
public class Zone extends Etaj{

Zone zonaE1,zoneE2,zoneE3,zoneE4;
String TAG = "myLogs";
int idZona;
public void adaugaZoneLaEtaj1()
{
    creazaEtaje();

    for(int i = 0; i <  etaj1.length; i++)
    {

        zonaE1 = new Zone();
        zonaE1.setIdZona(i+1);

        Log.e(TAG, "ZONEE " + etaj1[zonaE1.getIdZona()]);

        for (int j = 0; j < etaj1[i].length; j++)
        {


            // this.etaj1[i][j] = zone;
            Log.e(TAG, "tile " + etaj1[i][j]);

        }
    }
}

public int getIdZona() {
    return idZona;
}

public void setIdZona(int idZona) {
    this.idZona = idZona;
}
```

my question is why can t i put 1 to this line
 Log.e(TAG, "ZONEE " + etaj1[zonaE1.getIdZona()]);
i want to add an id to that head element array , but it doesnt let me

getIdZone() its 1 and i want to add it to etaj1[i]; thats the first spot of the array

why can i do this  etaj1[i][j] = j+1;  but i cant do this
  etaj1[i] = i; Why ?

Comment: How is C++ related to your question?

Comment: my mistake i just noticed that

Comment: can you help me ?

Comment: how to instert   etaj1[i] = a number; ?

Answer (score 0):

etaj1 is a 2 dimensional array, so you could set etaj1[i] to be some one dimensional array, or you could set etaj1[i][0] to be a certain value to set the first element of the array to some number.  In this case, etaj1 has dimensions 1x9, so you could make etaj1 a one dimensional array.

Comment: i want to do like a contact list , A to have 1 2 3 4..9 than B to have 1 2 3 4...9 and there im tryn to edit the A,B... to put some index at the head row but doesnt let me..

Answer (score 0):

The arrays which you have named in series etaj1, etaj2 ... are all referred to as 2 dimensional arrays. Whenever you define an array as such:

```
int[] array1 = new int[8];
int[][] array2 = new int[8][8];
```

These are completely different things; the first array (array1) is a one dimensional array, where you can query any element with simply one parameter. If you were to draw array1, it would look like:

```
_________________
|0|1|2|3|4|5|6|7
_________________
```

Note that those numbers are the index numbers of the array.

Now, if you were to draw out array2, it would look like a chessboard, with a starting position of [0, 0] being the upper left square.

Hope this helps.

Comment: i want to do like a contact list , A to have 1 2 3 4..9 than B to have 1 2 3 4...9 and there im tryn to edit the A,B... to put some index at the head row but doesnt let me..